# For which values of $q$ and $\alpha$ does $\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^{n^\alpha}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let us consider the series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^{n^\alpha}, \qquad \qquad\qquad (*)$$ with $\alpha,\in \mathbb{Q}, n \in \mathbb{N}$. I know that the geometric series converges if $|q|<1$, but what can we say about the convergence of the series $(*)$?

Comment: $\beta$ needs to be positive, provided that you don´t want to mess with complex multivaluated functions.

Comment: Your series does not depend on $n$, be careful.

Comment: $n$ is never used in that sum, so it converges only when $q=0$. But you probably mean something else?

Comment: Technically, that isn't a geometric series, but it is close enough.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Indeed: that's the problem. What should I do?

Comment: You'll need $\alpha>0$ to assert it converges for any $|x|<1$.

Comment: Well, if you knew that it wasn't a geometric series, the first thing you should do is use correct terminology. It is never helpful in math or on this site to use the wrong terminology - it is hard to figure out what you know.

Comment: It's not even clear what the series means when $q$ is negative - what is $(-1)^{\sqrt 2}$, for example?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I've edited the question a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Claim: For fixed $a>0,0<q<1, q^{n^a} < 1/n^2$ for large $n.$ This shows $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}q^{n^a}<\infty$ for this range of $a,q.$ Proof of claim: This is equivalent to

$$n^a\ln q < -2\ln n,\,\, \text {or}\,\, \frac{n^a}{\ln n} > \frac {-2}{\ln q}$$

for large $n.$ (The inequality flipped because $\ln q < 0.$) Because $n^a/\ln n \to \infty,$ it is eventually above the positive constant $-2/\ln q,$ giving the claim.